# Blocks overlapping in front page

Tags: blocks

I have a problem with one block in my website, recently I noticed that it gets overlapped by the others, not allowing to be seen correctly and to click the links in it, it's the partner block at the bottom right of this website: http://www.esnbologna.org/

Any hints on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `<div>` with id `#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_partners-block` for the browser has an height of 0. Therefor, the most simple solution for you would be to set a static height for this element using CSS (i.e., the largest slide is currently 656px).

If you want the 'view all' link to be right below the slide that is shown to the user, in your situation I think the most easiest solution would be to alter the height of `#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_partners-block` using JavaScript (i.e., jQuery).

For more information on this, see this post: [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)